# Create a new year feature of actual_sales in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, pivot-table

I have a data frame in Pandas with approx two years of historical sales data from 2019 to 2022.

The timestamp ('yyyy-mm-dd') is the index column of the data frame.

Current columns are: index (timestamp), week_day, week_of_year, actual_sales

```
 timestamp    weekday  week_of_year actual_sales
 
yyyy-mm-dd   'monday'       1             $X
yyyy-mm-dd   'tuesday'      1             $X
yyyy-mm-dd   'wednesday'    1             $X
```

I want to create a side-by-side comparison of the previous year's sales.

This is how I want it to look:

```
 weekday   week_of_year 2020 2021  2022
 
'monday'         1       $X   $X    $X
'tuesday'        1       $X   $X    $X
'wednesday'      1       $X   $X    $X
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple and can be achieved using below set of instructions:

- Convert index to date-time object

`df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`

- Extract year from the index

`df['year'] = df.index.year`

- Now pivot the table with index being `weekday` and `week_of_year`, columns being `year` and values being `actual_sales`

`df_pivot = df.pivot(index=['weekday','week_of_year'], columns='year', values='actual_sales', aggfunc="sum", fill_value=0)`

Hope this gets the work done

Comment: This worked 

table = pd.pivot_table(df_mock, values='actual_sales', index=['week_of_year','weekday'], columns=['year'], aggfunc=np.sum)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The order of the weekdays is mixed... Is there a way to order these?

Comment: generate day of week as well and use that as index in pivot and then sort using it, day of week can be derived using `df.index.day_of_week`